# Swipe to delete still shows red background with garbage can, recyclerview not updating

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-canvas, swipe-gesture

I've implemented ItemToucherHelper.SimpleCallback to use swipe gesture inside of my recyclerview to delete an item and update the UI after deletion. Unfortunately, the red background and garbage can is still visible after swiping and the recyclerview isn't updating.

I've tried notifyDataSetChanged() in both the onSwipe() as well as the adapter itself, I've also tried notifyItemChanged(position) & notifyItemRemoved(position), but no change.

FeedAdapter.java

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import org.quietlip.voicescapstone.R;
import org.quietlip.voicescapstone.models.AudioModel;

import java.util.List;

import static com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI.TAG;

public class FeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedViewHolder> {
    private List<AudioModel> audioList;

    public FeedAdapter(List<AudioModel> audioList) {
        this.audioList = audioList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FeedViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view =
                LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feed_recording_item,
                        viewGroup, false);
        return new FeedViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FeedViewHolder feedViewHolder, int i) {
        feedViewHolder.onBind(audioList.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return audioList.size();
    }

    public void deleteItem(int position) {
        AudioModel recentlyDeletedItem = audioList.get(position);

        if (recentlyDeletedItem != null && recentlyDeletedItem.getAudioId() != null) {
            StorageReference stRef =
                    FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(recentlyDeletedItem.getUser().getUserId())
                            .child("audio").child(recentlyDeletedItem.getAudioId());
            stRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                }
            });

            FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            firestore.collection("users").document(recentlyDeletedItem.getUser().getUserId())
                    .collection("audio").document(recentlyDeletedItem.getAudioId())
                    .delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                }
            });
            audioList.remove(position);
            notifyItemChanged(position);

        }
    }
}
```

FeedSwipeDelete.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import org.quietlip.voicescapstone.R;
import org.quietlip.voicescapstone.recyclerview.FeedAdapter;

public class FeedSwipeDelete extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
    private static final String TAG = "Swipe";
    private FeedAdapter feedAdapter;
    private Drawable icon;
    private final ColorDrawable background;

    public FeedSwipeDelete(FeedAdapter adapter, Context context) {
        super(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT);
        this.feedAdapter = adapter;
        icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_delete);
        background = new ColorDrawable(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        feedAdapter.deleteItem(position);
        feedAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
//        feedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//        feedAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView,
                          @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                          @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder1) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView,
                            @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                            int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

        View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
        int backgroundCornerOffset = 20;
        int iconMargin = (itemView.getHeight() - icon.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2;
        int iconTop = itemView.getTop() + (itemView.getHeight() - icon.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2;
        int iconBottom = iconTop + icon.getIntrinsicHeight();

        if (dX > 0) {
            int iconLeft = itemView.getLeft() + iconMargin;
            int iconRight = iconLeft + icon.getIntrinsicWidth();
            icon.setBounds(iconLeft, iconTop, iconRight, iconBottom);
            background.setBounds(itemView.getLeft(), itemView.getTop(),
                    itemView.getLeft() + ((int) dX) + backgroundCornerOffset,
                    itemView.getBottom());
        } else if (dX < 0) {
            int iconLeft = itemView.getRight() - iconMargin - icon.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int iconRight = itemView.getRight() - iconMargin;
            icon.setBounds(iconLeft, iconTop, iconRight, iconBottom);
            background.setBounds(itemView.getRight() + ((int) dX) - backgroundCornerOffset,
                    itemView.getTop(), itemView.getRight(), itemView.getBottom());
        }  else {
            background.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
            icon.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        background.draw(c);
        icon.draw(c);

        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY,
                actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }
}
```

FeedViewHolder.java

```
public class VoicesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private static final String TAG = "PROUD";

    private ImageView playIv;
    private TextView title;
    private CircleImageView profilePic;
    private TextView username;
    private ImageView commentMic;
    private TextView timeStamp;

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    private String audioId;
    private String pathId;
    private StorageReference stRef;
    private UserModel user1;
    private AudioViewModel viewModel;

    public VoicesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        playIv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_play_btn);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_title);
        profilePic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_username);
        timeStamp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_stamp);
        commentMic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_comments_btn);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    }

    public void onBind(final AudioModel audio) {
        title.setText(audio.getTitle());
        audioId = audio.getAudioId();
        pathId = audio.getPathId();
        viewModel = new AudioViewModel(audio);
        timeStamp.setText(viewModel.getTimeStamp());
        user1 = CurrentUserManager.getCurrentUser();
        if (user1 != null) {
            username.setText(user1.getUserName());
            Picasso.get().load(user1.getImageUrl()).fit().into(profilePic);
        }
        playIv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //Create a loading spinner in place of the play button to indicate that audio is loading
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (user1 != null) {
                    stRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(user1.getUserId())
                            .child("audio").child(audioId);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: " + audioId);
                    stRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                                playIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_stopp);
                                startPlaying(uri);
                            } else {
                                playIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button);
                                mediaPlayer.stop();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        commentMic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goToCommentActivity();

            }
        });
    }

    private void startPlaying(Uri audio) {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(itemView.getContext(), audio);
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                playIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button);
                                mediaPlayer.reset();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                Log.d("VIEW HOLDER", String.valueOf(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("VIEW HOLDER", "prepare() failed");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "startPlaying: null");
        }
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    private void goToCommentActivity() {
        Intent commentActivityIntent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), CommentActivity.class);
        Log.d(TAG, "goToCommentActivity: Jose says goToCommentActivity " + user1);
        if(null != user1) {
            commentActivityIntent.putExtra("userid", user1.getUserId());
            commentActivityIntent.putExtra("audioid", audioId);
            commentActivityIntent.putExtra("pathid", pathId);
            itemView.getContext().startActivity(commentActivityIntent);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't see any error messages in the stacktrace, it should be deleted in the recyclerview but it's not. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7va4.png)

Comment: Where is the code for `feedViewHolder.onBind` ?

Comment: @Blundell I've edited my original post to include the viewholder w/ onBind